# Null properties are missing when returned by ActionResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My controller action method looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomerAddress(int CustomerId)
{
    customer =  await scope.ServiceProvider
                           .GetRequiredService<CustomerClient>()
                           .GetCustomerAddressAsyn(CustomerId);

    Ok(Customer);
}
```

The customer model object is as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int CustomerID { get; set; }
     public string CustomerName { get; set; }
     public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
     public string CustomerMiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

The `CustomerMiddleName` value is null when stored at this variable.

```
Customer customer =  await scope.ServiceProvider
                                .GetRequiredService<CustomerClient>()
                                .GetCustomerAddressAsyn(CustomerId);
```

but when doing this

```
return Ok(Customer);
```

the `CustomerMiddleName` property itself is missing from the Json response on the postman test. Unable to comprehend why this happening. Null value properties are missing here when returned by `OkObjectResult`

Comment: Maybe you have set this value to true in your service collection `options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = false;`

Comment: Could you please share your startup.cs codes? It seems that you have special settings which ignore the null value as @TheGeneral says.

Comment: Do not have this setting `options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = false;` anywhere .